# How do I run Lightroom on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine

I tried to install Lightroom opening with Wine and it did not work is there any other app that will run windows programs?

Comment: Please choose an answer as I would like to know your feedback because I'm in this situation now. What have you done? Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can install lightroom using playonlinux which is a frontend for wine. Many apps that don't install well on wine will install using playonlinux.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

If using AMD or Nvidia, you reportedly must use it with Nvidia or AMD proprietary drivers. If you use intel graphics, some people have had success with i5 but it may or may not work.

You can install the Nvidia or AMD proprietary drivers by clicking on Additional Drivers and selecting them from there.

[Click here for more info.](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2247.html)

[Also here.](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/comments-1275.html)

---

Alternatively, now that you are using linux, you might as well use [darktable](http://darktable.org) as an alternative:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install darktable
```

Comment: While we're recommending things, RawTherapee is also great - I found it simpler to get used to than darktable: http://rawtherapee.com/

Comment: @jocull Thanks, I'll check that out. You should submit this as an answer (just explain how  to install it though).

Answer (score 1):

Just don't try to run by Wine or any similar. I've already tried with many different configs, and my only choice was create a Windows virtual machine on Virtual Box, and config it with a lot of resources. It's too heavy and there is not a lot of people trying to make it work, unfortunately.

I'd suggest you dual boot (yes...), this VM try, and then, [**Darktable**](http://www.darktable.org/). After one or two weeks of adaptation, you'll see it's better than Lightroom.

Comment: I've tried the Playonlinux method. It works, but definetely, the application is not fully useful. For professional using, my case, it doesn't show enough performance, even in a octacore 16GB RAM PC.